# Detecting blog or forum software using python?

Tags: python

Is there a way beside checking for known signatures in the site content to find out what kind of software is the website running e.g vbbuliten,WP etc, preferably python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect which blog API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547/how-to-detect-which-blog-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re_generator = re.compile('<meta name="generator" content="(.*?)" /?>', re.IGNORECASE)
```

This might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Some sites will set the 'generator' meta-tag in the html head.